# how to change file extensions in windows 8? i tried and it will not recognize the change

Tags: python, windows-8

How do I change file extensions in windows 8? I tried and my system will not recognize the change.
I tried changing from .txt to .py for python so i can use in IDLE.

Comment: How did you try it? On the command line, right clicking? What happened? Did you end up with myfile.py.txt?

Comment: Yes that is it. Right click, Change title to .txt to .py and still gotten file.txt.py. After that i changed the "Open with"  in the properties from word to python and nothing still. (basically I am trying to create an Python IDLE file)

Answer (score 1):

I created a file called `myfile.txt`. It showed up in Explorer as `myfile.txt`. If you just see `myfile` (no extension), then go to Folder Options, Advanced, and uncheck "Hide extensions for known file types".

I Right-clicked `myfile.txt`, selected Rename, and Windows selected just "myfile", not ".txt". I changed the selection to "txt", overwrote it with "py" and hit enter. Windows popped up a message warning that I was changing the extension. I clicked OK and the file was renamed.

An alternate approach is to open a command prompt, cd to the directory and use "move" to change the name.

Yet another option, if you are doing this from a text editor, click "Save As", change the save dialog's "Save As Type" drop-down to All Files, change the name to .py and hit OK. You end up with a .txt and a .py.